# How to sum a row in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

and I'm trying to combine the 'White' and 'Other' categories into a category called "non-southasian", while also removing "White" and 'Other' entries. The new categroy should have a freq which is white+other, however im struggling to find a way to do this in dpylr

So it should result in

```
Ethnicity     Freq
South asian    26
non-southasian 214
```

This is because im trying to do post hoc analysis on a chi squared goodness of fit test by doing single comparisons between groups proportions and their expected proportions to see where the significance lies

Comment: Try `df1$ethnicity != "South Asian" <- "non-South Asian"; aggregate(freq ~ ethnicity, df1, sum)` or with `dplyr` `df1 %>% group_by(ethnicity = case_when(ethnicity %in% c("White", "Other") ~ "Non South Asian", TRUE ~ ethnicity)) %>% summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))`

Comment: I get errors when trying to do both versions, with dpylr the errors are
Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `ethnicity = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: with the other solution i get the error : Error in ethnicity_distribution$ethnicity != "South Asian" <- "non-South Asian" : 
  could not find function "!=<-"

Comment: In the first piece of code, there is a mistake. sorry.  `df1$ethnicity[df1$ethnicity != "South Asian"] <- "non-South Asian"`

Comment: the error in case_when is not clear.  Can you take it out of group_by and add `mutate` i.e. `df %>% mutate(ethnicity = case_when(ethnicity %in% c("White", "Other") ~ "Non South Asian", TRUE ~ ethnicity)) %>% group_by(ethnicity) %>%  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))`

Comment: i get these errors :
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `ethnicity = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: and for the other method i now get 
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ethnicity_distribution$ethnicity != "South Asian",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: I assumed your column is `character` class.  if not `df$ethnicity <- as.character(df$ethnicity)` and then apply the same code.  Or if you want to keep it as factor, you may use `fct_lump` etc functions from `forcats` for changing some levels to a single level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%  # just in case freq is not numeric
  group_by(ethnicity = ifelse(ethnicity == "South Asian", "South asian", "non-southasian")) %>%
  summarise(Freq= sum(freq))
```

```
ethnicity       Freq
  <chr>          <int>
1 non-southasian   214
2 South asian       26
```

data

```
structure(list(ethnicity = c("South Asian", "White", "Other"), 
    freq = c(26, 168, 46)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```